# JavaScript: simple counter with pause between the values doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starter in JavaScript and I try to make simple code to print numbers (0-100) , but with pause in printing, for every next number(for exp. 3 seconds pause). 
Code doesn't work properly... It waits 3 seconds and print the last number (100 in my case). Can you help me, where is my mistake?
This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">    
 function  funkcija_polnac()
 { 
     var i = 0;
     while (i <= 100) {
             setTimeout(function(){ document.write(i + '%');}, 3000);            
             i++;                 
     }
 }</script> 

</head>
<body>     
  <div style="margin: 0px auto;"  onclick="funkcija_polnac()">Start</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably should do some research on closures in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are running your while before the timeout happens. Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function funkcija_polnac(i)
    { 
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = i + "%";
   
        if (--i > -1) {
            setTimeout(function () { funkcija_polnac(i); }, 3000);
        }
    }
</script> 

</head>
<body>     
  <div style="margin: 0px auto;" onclick="funkcija_polnac(5)">Start</div>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

What your code does is schedule 101 function callbacks, all of which will happen one right after another about three seconds after the code runs, and all of which will use the `i` **variable**, not its value as of when the function was created. So after three seconds you get 101 iterations of the value 101. This is because the functions you're creating are "closures over" the `i` variable (more accurately, the context in which the variable was created), and so they have an enduring reference to the variable and see its value as of when they use it, not as of when they were created. More about closures on my blog: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Or at least, that's what you'd see if it weren't that `document.write`, when used after initial parsing, blows away the page entirely. Basically: Don't use `document.write`. :-)

To fix it, you would schedule a *single* call to a function that, once it's run, schedules the next call. And you'd use the DOM or similar rather than `document.write` to see the output.

Example:

```js
// NOTE: I used 30ms rather than 3000ms so it runs faster
var i = 0;
showOne();

function showOne() {
  display(i);
  ++i;
  if (i <= 100) {
    setTimeout(showOne, 30); // You'd really want 3000
  }
}

// Displays the given message by adding a paragraph element to the page
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```